# Entering text in textarea using vbs but text count is still Zero

Tags: vbscript

I am entering text in textarea in a webpage using vbscript, but the count of the textbox shows zero , So couldn't proceed further.

[image]

My code:

```
objIE2.Document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0).value = "Sent from"
WScript.Sleep 500
```

The word count is updated as:

Using keyup, everytime a word is entered the span count increases.

```
<textarea name="postForm:message" id="postForm:message" cols="5000" rows="15" style="width:534px; min-width:98.5%; max-width:98.5%;" class="is-maxlength"></textarea> 
<span class="maxlength-feedback" style="visibility: visible; display: none;">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there should be some event listener like "keydown", "keyup", "hover", etc. in your webpage to verify and update the text count in the textbox.

In a similar case I encountered, after updating the textbox, I used to change the text count manually to a "non-zero" value.

```
objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0).value = "Sent from"                      

Set NodeList = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("Your tag") 

For Each Elem In NodeList

if Elem.innerHTML = "0" then

Elem.innerHTML = "9"

end if
```

Now the web page will be updated as "9 characters used, of 2000 available."

Hope it will work as expected.

Good luck!

Comment: Pandiyan, 
i used this in my code, it worked, Thank alot, Thumbs Up !!